# OpenCart Securimage PhpCaptcha weird behavior

Tags: php, opencart, captcha

I have downloaded securimage library from phpcaptcha, unzippped it into system/library/securimage and done the following:

index.php:

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/securimage/securimage.php');
$registry->set('securimage', new Securimage($registry));
```

catalog\view\theme\my_theme\template\information\contact.tpl:

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<img id="captcha_img" src="index.php?route=information/contact/securimage" alt="CAPTCHA Image" /> 
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha_img').src = 'system/library/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">
<img src="system/library/securimage/images/refresh.png" height="25" width="25" alt="Reload Image" onclick="this.blur()" align="bottom" border="0"></a>
<label for="captcha" class="required"><?php echo $entry_captcha; ?></label>
<input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" size="31" maxlength="6" value="" onblur="check('captcha');" />
<span class="txt"><?php echo $entry_captcha_tip; ?></span>
<br />
<?php if ($error_captcha) { ?><span class="error_txt"><?php echo $error_captcha; ?></span><?php } ?>
...
```

catalog\controller\information\contact.php:

```
protected function validate() {
    $this->log->write('SESSION CODE: ' . $this->session->data['captcha']);// 2nd variable in log
$this->log->write('REQUEST CODE: ' . $this->request->post['captcha']);// 3rd variable in log
    ...

    if (empty($this->session->data['captcha']) || ($this->session->data['captcha'] != $this->request->post['captcha'])) {
        $this->error['captcha'] = $this->language->get('error_captcha');
    }
}

public function securimage() {
    $this->session->data['captcha'] = $this->securimage->getCode();
$this->log->write('IMAGE CODE: ' . $this->session->data['captcha']); // 1st variable in log
$this->securimage->show();
}   
...
```

Now, this is how it works:

1. Image loads fine, and reloads fine as well
2. Say, the first image code is abc123
3. I enter abc123 into captcha field, press submit
4. The error['name'] shows abc123, while error['email'] shows some other code
5. Now say, the image shows def456, I enter def456 into the captcha field and press submit
6. Now the error['name'] shows def456, but the error['email'] shows abc123!

Can anyone explain what's going on? How is it possible that the $this->session->data['captcha']; is 2 steps behind? Please help me fix it. How can I actually get the correct image code before the submit. Thank you.

[EDIT]
The weird behavior continues... (considering the logged variables):

1. The first time I visit the contact page, 1st variable **IMAGE CODE = kzycbc**, 2nd and 3rd are empty, the image on the page shows code **eslmmg**
2. I reload the page (without filling in the form), 1st variable **IMAGE CODE = *eslmmg**, 2nd and 3rd are empty, the image on the page shows code **cnsf6u**
3. I fill in the form and enter **cnsf6u** in the captcha field and press submit, the log shows **SESSION CODE = eslmmg**, **REQUEST CODE = cnsf6u**, **IMAGE CODE = cnsf6u**, image on the page has **zvkht7**
4. I enter **zvkht7** in the captcha field and press submit, the log shows **SESSION CODE = cnsf6u**, **REQUEST CODE = zvkht7**, **IMAGE CODE = zvkht7**, image on the page has a new code

It looks to me, first, the IMAGE CODE is loaded twice on the first page load, the getCode() takes the first code, while the image on the page loads again, which is then stored in the session variable and shown as IMAGE CODE. This only happens on the very first load of the page. Then, after the second submit, the session takes the value from the previous submit, not from the one just made, while the request code is correct.

What does this tell you? Can anyone help please? The IMAGE CODE and SESSION CODE should be the same. Why do these value differ in securimage() and validate()? As the REQUEST CODE = IMAGE CODE, looks like the image code is correctly taken by the securimage() session, but as the SESSION CODE != IMAGE CODE, where does validate() session takes its value from? Why does it only update the value on the next submit?

[SOLVED]

The solution is much simpler than one might think. All it needs is simply this:

```
protected function validate() {
    ...

    if (!$this->securimage->check($this->request->post['captcha'])) {
        $this->error['captcha'] = $this->language->get('error_captcha');
    }
}

public function securimage() {
    $this->securimage->show();
}
```

And no need to use the session! Looks like Securimage handles that itself. Huge thank to drew0!

Comment: Does this code: `$this->securimage->getCode();` always generate the same code as in image ? Seems like an issue with the secureimage library code.

Comment: Yes, it generates always the correct code, but only 2 submits behind

Comment: `$this->securimage->getCode();` - always generate the code 2 submits behind ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Please see my points 1-6 above. This is how it works. The image loads, `$this->securimage->getCode();` should get the code and show it after the form submit, but it only shows it after the 2nd submit. Well, after thinking about it, it's actually 1 step behind, not 2

Comment: so the problem is with your library code which you've not shared here.

Comment: This is what I have encountered few times and that I call myself as *session lag* - the variable stored into session at one request is present only after the next request... Please, inspect the OpenCart logging possibility and do the following: in `secureimage()` method right after `$this->session->data['captcha'] = $this->securimage->getCode();` line insert this line and come back with result being logged: `$this->log->write('CAPTCHA CODE: ' . $this->session->data['captcha'])`.

Comment: @SankarV the securimage library code can be downloaded from here: http://www.phpcaptcha.org/download/

Comment: @shadyyx will do shortly. BTW, why do I have the lag with the securimage, but no lag with the default OC's captcha?

Comment: @shadyyx here's the log: `2014-03-27 22:08:40 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: code in /home/***/public_html/system/library/securimage/securimage.php on line 1154
2014-03-27 22:08:40 - CAPTCHA CODE: 
2014-03-27 22:09:02 - CAPTCHA CODE: wtabbt
2014-03-27 22:09:15 - CAPTCHA CODE: hcdu5u`

Comment: BTW, how do I insert a line break into this comment field? Thank you.

Comment: @shadyyx line 1154 in securimage.php is `return $code['code'];`. See, the first code is empty, 'wtabbt' was the first one I entered, so it get the correct code. The 'hcdu5u' is the second one I entered, which is also correct. But for some reason the session lags

Comment: Could it be something to do with the OS's or actual server settings? Cache?

Comment: @shadyyx just to clarify the log, the codes are the ones which apeared in the image (which I also entered)

Comment: I know, I was expecting this, but even strange is that for the first time it is empty in the log. You can enter a new line to this log by using `'CAPTCHA CODE: ' . $this->session->data['captcha']) . "\n"`. Look to the OC's default captcha how (**when**) the code is generated and stored into the session - maybe there is something different in the implementation...

Comment: @shadyyx here's the OC's captcha code: 
 public function captcha() {
  //$this->load->library('captcha');
  //$captcha = new Captcha();
  //$this->session->data['captcha'] = $captcha->getCode();
  //$captcha->showImage();
 }

Comment: Could it be something to do with the way OC's registry works? See, the OC's doesn't use the registry, but instantiates the class in the contact.php

Comment: @shadyyx here's the log again: 2014-03-27 22:43:09 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: code in /home/***/public_html/system/library/securimage/securimage.php on line 1154
2014-03-27 22:43:09 - CAPTCHA CODE: 
CAPTCHA CODE: 
2014-03-27 22:43:32 - CAPTCHA CODE: e3atnf
CAPTCHA CODE: e3atnf
2014-03-27 22:43:46 - CAPTCHA CODE: s7kubh
CAPTCHA CODE: s7kubh. The first codes are empty

Comment: @shadyyx I have changed the securimage() to `$this->load->library('securimage/securimage');
  $securimage = new Securimage();
  $this->session->data['captcha'] = $securimage->getCode();
  $this->log->write('CAPTCHA CODE: ' . $this->session->data['captcha']);
  $securimage->show();` and now the log looks like `2014-03-27 22:47:15 - CAPTCHA CODE: r3rtes
2014-03-27 22:47:37 - CAPTCHA CODE: bpm3rv
2014-03-27 22:48:01 - CAPTCHA CODE: 5ranfn
`. The 1st value is not empty now, but it actually was 'bpm3rv'

Comment: Could it be something to do with this: `...this may be due to a problem with the PHP session that is used to keep track of the user and what their code is. It is possible that the session name being used in securimage_show.php differs from the session name used in the script that does the code validation. It is common for other software platforms to use a session name other than the PHP default. If this is the case, you must determine what session name is used by the software and use the same session name in securimage_show.php and securimage_play.php.`?

Comment: If the above would be true then You would never see the code from captcha in your session. OK, now it looks like the method `secureimage()` is called twice during one request - first with code *r3rtes* which is also stored into the session and second one with code *bpm3rv* which is shown in the image and will be present in the session on next request... Try to inspect somehow whether it is called twice or not... It's really hard to debug your code when I do not have this as running copy locally... The OC's default captcha generates the code in constructor - does the SecurImage do it same way?

Comment: Why are you calling `$this->load->library('securimage/securimage');`? Shouldn't it be only `$this->load->library('securimage');` ???

Comment: @shadyyx If `secureimage()` was called twice, wouldn't it keep the session variable in line or ahead of the submits, rather than lagging? I've also done this: `$this->log->write(session_name());
  $this->log->write($this->securimage->session_name);` and the log shows the 1st value is `PHPSESSID` while the second is empty.

Comment: @shadyyx No, the library has a whole folder called `securimage` which has got a `securimage.php` in it

Comment: If you do `$registry->set('securimage', new Securimage($registry));` then you cannot do `$this->load->library('securimage/securimage');` but you should call the library as it was set, thus `$this->load->library('securimage');`. OK, and can you set the session name for secure image somehow?

Comment: I only did this `$this->load->library('securimage/securimage');` to check if it's gonna make any difference. The library was set like this: `require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/securimage/securimage.php');`

Comment: Doesn't the library path mean the first securimage is a folder name, the second is a php file name? And How can I set the `public $session_name = 'PHPSESSID';` through `$this->securimage` instead of hard coding in the file? Thanks

Comment: I've hard coded `public $session_name = 'PHPSESSID';` in securimage.php, the log shows the same session names, but the problem with the code is still here. So it's not the session name problem

Comment: Please see further info in the main question.

Comment: @user665327 In your validate function, how come you are not just using `$this->securimage->check($this->request->post['captcha']))`?  If you are using session storage, let securimage store/retrieve the codes rather than have your application do it.  If you need to bootstrap any special session options, modify securimage_show.php to include your opencart script before the `$img = new Securimage();` call and it will latch onto the existing session.

Comment: @drew010 THAT WORKED!!! `if (!$this->securimage->check($this->request->post['captcha'])) {` is all it needs. Wow, the answer is proved again to be simpler than I thought. Thank you very very very much. That session thing drove me up the wall for the past week. I just couldn't think of anything what could be wrong with the code. Thanks, mate :)

Comment: @user665327 Glad to help.  Are you making a plugin for opencart or just integrating it into your site?  I am the author of securimage so if you are making a plugin I'd love to see the finished product.

Comment: @drew010 Yes, I'm developing a plugin for OpenCart. I've got it working and now it works perfectly. Thank you for your help. Hope I have some free time soon to finish the plugin and upload it to OpenCart